# jupyter does not run code outside of the default directory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I startup jupyter and it goes to the default directory c:/users/gary and I can load and run ipynb files with not errors.

When I browse to another directory. I can load a ipynb file but when I try to run the file it does not run but I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'html' 
(C:\Users\gary\Documents\pythonscripts\html.py)
[W 16:35:23.027 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 16:35:23.027 NotebookApp] Kernel 0d40f433-dd0f-475a-af0b-a5214fc9980c 
died, removing from map.
[W 16:36:08.042 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 
0d40f433-dd0f-475a-af0b-a5214fc9980c
[E 16:36:08.044 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found 
(Kernel does not exist: 0d40f433-dd0f-475a-af0b-a5214fc9980c)
```

Updated the errors

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to "Start Jupyter from Default Directory" and "Load" Notebooks from the File menu in Jupyter.

Comment: That works but I don't want all my scripts in my home directory. I want to be in documents/pythonscripts

Comment: Then you need to run "jupyter notebook C:/path/to/your/directory" in Command Prompt

Comment: Here is the errors I get:ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'html' (C:\Users\gary\Documents\pythonscripts\html.py)
[W 16:35:23.027 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 16:35:23.027 NotebookApp] Kernel 0d40f433-dd0f-475a-af0b-a5214fc9980c died, removing from map.
[W 16:36:08.042 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 0d40f433-dd0f-475a-af0b-a5214fc9980c
[E 16:36:08.044 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 0d40f433-dd0f-475a-af0b-a5214fc9980c)